# Ngx-mat-datetime-picker with compatible range picker

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I there a compatible module that lets you use `ngx-mat-datetime-picker` with a range picker too?
I've tried using `mat-date-range-input` but it wont work. I'm using angular 11 and @angular/material@11.1.0

I'm working on a search component that lets you choose a date, from a danamic form and it works like this

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dynamicInputMode === dynamicInputModes.Search">
  <div [formGroup]="dateForm">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="small poppins flex-grow font-15">
        <input formControlName="start" matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="pickerFrom" placeholder="From:">
        <input formControlName="end" matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="pickerTo" placeholder="To: ">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerFrom"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #pickerFrom [enableMeridian]="true"></ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

But I need something like this

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dynamicInputMode === dynamicInputModes.Search">
  <div [formGroup]="dateForm">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="small poppins flex-grow font-15">
      <mat-date-range-input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker">
        <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="From:">
        <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="To: ">
      </mat-date-range-input>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker [enableMeridian]="true"></ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Obviously I get this error because `[ngxMatDatetimePicker]=""` its not a known directive for `mat-date-range-input`
[image]

So the final question, is there a module I can use as a range picker with `ngx-mat-datetime-picker`?

P.S.: There's no tag for `ngx-mat-datetime-picker`